# React.js: Save items after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing a simple Todolist in react.js. So far I'm able to save my objects
to LocalStorage, but when I refresh the page the Todo elements are disappearing.

```js
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import TodoList from './TodoList.jsx'

const AddTodo = () => {

    const [newTodo, setNewTodo] = useState('')
    const [list, setList] = useState([])
    
    const handleSubmit = () => {

            const todoItem = {
                id:Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
                value:newTodo
            }

            if(todoItem){
                setList([...list,todoItem]) 
                setNewTodo('')    
            }
            /*gets the oldlist and whats inside of it and adds the new item */ 
            console.log(list)
            
 
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(list));
    }, [list])

    useEffect(() => {
        const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('list'));
        if(data){
            setList(data)
        }
        
    }, [])
   
    return (
        <div className="input_container">
             <form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
                <input type="text"
                onChange={e => setNewTodo(e.target.value)}
                className="todo-input" 
                placeholder="Write Todo.." 
                value={newTodo} 
                name="text"/>
           
                <button onClick={() => handleSubmit()} className="add-todo-button">
                    Add Todo
                </button>
            </form>

            <TodoList list={list} newTodo={newTodo}/>
          
        </div>
    )
}

export default AddTodo
```

Comment: You're setting the localStorage before you retrieve the last saved value in your first useEffect, and then immediately retrieving the newly set empty array in the the second. You can simply reverse the order of your `useEffects` or better yet implement the answer below.

Comment: Search for Global States - like Redux for example
You can try to parse the objects into JSON and save it then in the localStorage

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the todo list from local storage in your state when you create the state. Every time the page refreshes, it will get the initial state from local storage. If it had something otherwise it will set it to `[]` like this.

```
  const [newTodo, setNewTodo] = useState('')
  const [list, setList] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("list")) || [])
```

This is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Below part is not useful.

```
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(list));
}, [list])
```

When page is mounted, it will set the localStorage as [] because you set [] as default value of list.
Here is my solution to help you.

```
const [list, setList] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("list")) || [])
const handleSubmit = () => {

        const todoItem = {
            id:Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
            value:newTodo
        }

        if(todoItem){
            setList([...list,todoItem]) 
            setNewTodo('')    
        }
        /*gets the oldlist and whats inside of it and adds the new item */ 
        console.log(list)

        // Store the value in localStorage
        localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(list));

}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

It would be useful if you can take a look the useEffect again

Answer (score 0):

This effect

```
    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(list));
    }, [list])
```

will run every time the component is mounted. Which means that as soon as it's mounted, the effect will run and clear the value stored in the localStorage.

Setting your localStorage value inside your event handler (i.e. handleSubmit) instead of using an effect is a much better approach here.

```
    const handleSubmit = () => {

            const todoItem = {
                id:Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
                value:newTodo
            }

            if(todoItem){
                setList([...list,todoItem]) 
                setNewTodo('')    
            }
            /*gets the oldlist and whats inside of it and adds the new item */ 
            console.log(list)

            // Store the value in localStorage
            localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(list));
 
    }
```

Comment: except then the storage update needs to be implemented for every method that sets `list` which isn't very DRY. Better to just learn the ins and outs of useEffect and apply it appropriately.

Comment: If you wanted to make it DRY, you could create an `updateList` function that calls both the `setList `and `localStorage.setItem` functions. AFAIK the react team recommends doing most of your side effects in event handlers, and avoiding useEffect unless you have no other option: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/keeping-components-pure#where-you-can-cause-side-effects. This page should include more details once it's ready: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect

Comment: Your comment should be in the answer, it's far more descriptive (and offers references) than *'is a much better approach'*...